# Netsuite form not redirecting

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have created a form in netsuite such that after it has been posted it should redirect to the the selected record. It's not occuring - what am I doing wrong?

```
 if (request.getMethod() == 'GET') {
     var slcustomer = form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select',
                                    'Customer', 'customer');
     form.addSubmitButton('Submit'); //For submiting as i will check for post back  
     response.writePage(form); //Write the form or  display the form
 } else {
     if (request.getMethod() == 'POST') { 
         var task = request.getParameter('slcustomer');
         nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'task', null, false);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your code inside a suitelet function and it worked for me.

```
function suitelet(request, response){
    if (request.getMethod() == 'GET') {
        var form = nlapiCreateForm('My Custom Form', false);
         var slcustomer = form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select',
                                        'Customer', 'customer');
         form.addSubmitButton('Submit'); //For submiting as i will check for post back  
         response.writePage(form); //Write the form or  display the form
     } else {
         if (request.getMethod() == 'POST') { 
             var customerid = request.getParameter('custpage_selectfield');
             nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'selected id', customerid); 
             nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'task', null, false);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: var form = nlapiCreateForm('My Custom Form', false);   plz explain why you hv give false parameter.

Comment: nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'task', null, false); after removing the '' from the task also it is not goin in th erequired record...........instead throwing a n error i.e.  identifier

Comment: Did you try putting the above code snippet. Are you still getting error?

Comment: `nlapiCreateForm(title, hideNavbar)`

Parameters

`title {string} [required]` - The title for the form 
`hideNavbar {boolean} [optional] `- Set to true if the navigation bar should be hidden on the Suitelet. Setting to true enables “popup page” use cases in which the popup can be created with the UI Objects API rather than HTML.
When hideNavbar is set to false, the standard NetSuite navigation appears on the form or popup. Note that this navigation bar contains links to pages that require users to be logged in to access.

Comment: see the problem is that we i have to take the id choosen from  var slcustomer = form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select',
                                        'Customer', 'customer');      and after post back i have to redirect the page to that selected record by if (request.getMethod() == 'POST') { 
             var task = request.getParameter('slcustomer');
             nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'task', null, false);

Comment: I'm sorry if I understood it wrong. could you please tell me your exact error.

Comment: for example var slcustomer = form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select',
                                        'Customer', 'customer'); not able to take the id of the selected customer.

Comment: Ok, instead of using `var task = request.getParameter('slcustomer');` try using `request.getParameter('custpage_selectfield');`

Comment: Updated my answer please check once and let me know if still you're unable to fetch the id.

Comment: after doing the same the new error is coming : The record type [1264] is invalid.

Comment: now i have done the following changes: var task = request.getParameter('custpage_selectfield');
               nlapiLogExecution('Debug', 'error', 'its not working');
                //nlapiSetRedirectURL( 'RECORD', 'task',id, false );
                nlapiResolveURL('RECORD','task');         now no error is coming but blank page is coming.

Comment: because you wanted to redirect to a task  with an id that doesn't exist. Note : You're getting the customer id not the task id. Again when you're redirecting you're expecting to have a task with that id.(Which is wrong). I'm not sure what you really intend to do here with that customer id. But if you intend to redirect to that customer page then follow @Rusty Shackles.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slcustomer = form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select',
                                    'Customer', 'customer');
```

This line creates a drop down list of Customer records.

```
var task = request.getParameter('custpage_selectfield');
nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'selected id', task);
nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'task', null, false);
```

The task variable should contain the internal id of the selected customer.  Your nlapiSetRedirectURL call is incorrect.  If you want to redirect to the selected customer, it should be

```
nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD', 'customer', task);
```